# Temporary add role by token for a particular page to anonymous user

Tags: users

I have a specific task: I need to give a temporary access to particular unpublished nodes for anonymous users using access token. Anonymous is a key feature, so I can't create a limited user account by some reasons.

I found a rough temporary solution by adding a field "access token" to my node type, creating a role with access to unpublished nodes (using view unpublished module) and by changing user_access function. I added the following strings:

```
 if ($_GET['access_token'] && arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) {

        $node = node_load(arg(1));

        if (isset($node->field_access_token['und'][0]['value']) && $node->field_access_token['und'][0]['value'] == $_GET['access_token']) {

            $account->roles[6] = 'unpublishedaccess';
        }
    }
```

How can I do similar but without changing Drupal core files?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this question is about D7, you could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this, combined with enforcing the usage of an URL argument which must include the correct token.

Here is an example of a relative path you could use/enforce: `/node/123?SomeUrlArg=456`, which would be for the node with node id = `123` and which uses an URL argument named `SomeUrlArg` and with the value of that URL argument `456` (obviously, each node can have its own argument value).

To implement this, you would create a custom rule that looks like so:

- **Rules Event**: Drupal is initializing (you must use this event, otherwise you're too late).
- **Rules Condition**: NOT (Check if the URL argument (=`SomeUrlArg`) is present and that its value matches the value of your `field_access_token`).

  Note the **NOT** in this Rules Condition: you only want to perform the Rules Action below if either the argument is absent OR if its value doesn't match with the `field_access_token` value.

  To be able to specify these Rules Conditions, you can use the [Rules URL argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. For more details about this module, refer to my answer to "[How to use Rules to redirect a user based on URL argument?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189310/how-to-use-rules-to-redirect-a-user-based-on-url-argument/189355#189355)".
- **Rules Action**: perform a redirect to whatever relative path that fits your needs (but not to `/node/123` of course).